# Adjacency matrix into edge objects yielding memory addresses rather than true values

Tags: c++, matrix, prims-algorithm

I am having an issue with a program I am working on which is supposed to read in an adjacency matrix, create 'Edge' objects consisting of two vertexes as well as the weight of the edge connecting them. My read in loop seems to be working fine as when I view the array values each one yields the correct data. Only when I attempt to pass the array to my functions: "minedge" and "mirror" do the vertexes instead show up as either incredibly small or large numbers. I would very much appreciate any help in debugging the issue.

Here is the adjacency matrix I am given which I am attempting to create an MST from:

```
0 0 7 0 9 0
0 0 5 0 0 6
7 5 0 3 0 2
0 0 3 0 0 2
9 0 0 0 0 1
0 6 2 2 1 0
```

This is my class for the Graph that I will be reading in and creating:

```
 #ifndef GRAPH_H
    #define GRAPH_H

    #include "fstream"
    #include "Edge.h"
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

class Graph
{
public:
    Graph()
    {
    }
    ~Graph()
    {
    }

    void InitMatrix() // READS IN EACH NON-ZERO VALUE FROM GIVEN GRAPH AND CREATES EDGES.
    {
        fin.open("adjmatrix.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < 6 ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                fin >> tempwt;
                if (tempwt > 0)
                {
                    EdArray[cnt] = new Edge(i,j,tempwt);
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    void InitMST()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                MST[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    bool minEdge(Edge array[])
    {
        for (EdArrayCnt; ;EdArrayCnt++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 16 ;i++)
            {
                if (array[EdArrayCnt].vertexOne() == array[i].vertexOne())
                    if (array[EdArrayCnt].vertexTwo() != array[i].vertexTwo())
                        if (array[EdArrayCnt].weight() < array[i].weight())
                        {
                            tempcnt = EdArrayCnt;
                            Insert(EdArrayCnt, array);
                            Mirror(tempcnt, array);
                            return true;
                        }
                        //return false;
            }
        }
    }

    bool Mirror(int cnt, Edge array[])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            cout << array[cnt].vertexOne() << " " << array[i].vertexTwo() << endl;
            if (array[cnt].vertexOne() == array[i].vertexTwo())
                if (array[cnt].vertexTwo() == array[i].vertexOne())
                    if (array[cnt].weight() == array[i].weight())
                        {
                        Insert(i, array);
                        return true;
                        }
            //return false;
        }
    }


    void Insert(int loc, Edge array[])
    {
        MST[array[loc].vertexOne()][array[loc].vertexTwo()] = array[loc].weight();
    }

    void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                cout << MST[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }


    void buildMatrix()
    {
        minEdge(*EdArray);
        print();

    }


private:
    ifstream fin;
    int cnt = 0;
    int tempwt, EdArrayCnt = 0, tempcnt;
    Edge* EdArray[20]; //MST For Initial Graph.
    int MST[6][6]; //New Graph.

};

#endif
```

This is the Edge class:

```
#ifndef EDGE_H
#define EDGE_H

using namespace std;

class Edge
{
public:

    Edge()
    {   
    }

    Edge(int v, int v2, int w)
    {
        vertOne = v;
        vertTwo = v2;
        wt = w;
    }
    ~Edge()
    {
    }

    int vertexOne()
    {
        return vertOne;
    }

    int vertexTwo()
    {
        return vertTwo;
    }

    int weight()
    {
        return wt;
    }

private:
    int vertOne, vertTwo, wt;

};

#endif
```

Lastly here is the driver function main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Graph.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Graph G;

    G.InitMST();
    G.InitMatrix();
    G.buildMatrix();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `Mirror` and `minEdge` functions are not guaranteed to return values, thus the behavior of your program is undefined if that `return` in either of those functions is not invoked.  Why did you comment out `return false;`?  By doing that, you've caused the issue.

Comment: [Here is your program, and look for that special output message](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/599de925b3196a83).  Note that you return nothing, thus the behavior is undefined.  Also, note the warnings the compiler is giving you.